# To walk two times a same ANTLR parser gives an error message. Is it a bug?

Tags: parsing, antlr

I am not sure whether it is a bug or not. But with the following simple ANTLR grammar that recognizes a token "program",

```
grammar w;
options{ 
  language = Java;
  ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}
root : 'program' ;
```

The following test rig that tries to go through the grammar TWICE gives an error message although it compiles

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.*;
import antlr.CommonAST;


public class wT{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      wLexer lexer =      new wLexer(new ANTLRStringStream ("program"));
      wParser parser = new wParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
      System.out.println("###Test1");

      parser.root();
      parser.root();
      System.out.println("ok for w.g gramma");

  }
}
```

The error message invoked by ANT is,

```
bash-3.2$ ant testrig
Buildfile: /Users/fuzl/while-comp/trunk/_test/build.xml

antlr:

compile:
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/fuzl/while-comp/trunk/_test

testrig:
     [java] ###Test1
     [java] ok for w.g gramma
     [java] line 1:7 missing 'program' at '<EOF>'
```

Very interestingly, the last line

```
     [java] line 1:7 missing 'program' at '<EOF>'
```

is due to the two times "parser.root()" of the testrig, and this error message disappears when only one parser.root() is used.

I guess that parser.root() changes the object "parser". If so, this should be a bug, right?

Answer (score 2):

You already walked all the way to the end of the input -- there's nothing left to parse when you call it again.

You might find the [`setCharStream()`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/classorg_1_1antlr_1_1runtime_1_1_lexer.html#3380a35e1483bf6d7d0f05deebf80631) or [`reset()`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/classorg_1_1antlr_1_1runtime_1_1_lexer.html#b3117cb1e6c605fdd305923fde698232) methods useful.